# Debugger kills the application with no explanation (on a CryptoStream.ReadByte() call)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, encryption, .net-3.5, visual-studio-debugging

**EDIT:** I identified the problem.

The constructor for my object was initializing a file stream in writing mode, whether or not we were about to encrypt or decrypt the file. Even though the writing file stream would be closed before decrypting (another file stream used for that purpose), it was still causing the silent crash. Now it works fine.

So it looks like a rather ordinary file access issue. It's a pitty that `CryptoStream` does not handle it as an exception.

Thanks for the suggestions - I'll have a look at **ProcDump** and **WinDbg**.

---

I just created a small application to read and decrypt a file from local HDD.

Visual Studio debugger kills the application without any message or explanation at all. It happens when the line `read = crypto.ReadByte()` in the following code is executed.

```
            try
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    // the stream that was used for encryption
                    file.Close();
                }
                var provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                provider.Key = Key;
                provider.IV = Key;
                var ict = provider.CreateDecryptor();
                var bytes = new List<byte>();
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    crypto = new CryptoStream(stream, ict, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                    var decrypted = new MemoryStream();
                    Int32 read;
                    try
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            read = crypto.ReadByte(); // the application dies here
                            if (read != -1) bytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(read));
                        }
                        while (read != -1);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // we never get here
                        decrypted.Close();
                    }

                };
                return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                // we never get here either                            
                crypto.Close();
                return x.Message;
            }
```

**What I tried and ruled out:**

1. No exceptions are thrown. We never enter `finally` nor `catch`. I also enabled `Break when an exception is thrown`, but it makes no difference. No indication of any exception.
2. Publishing the application (ClickOnce) and running it has the same effect.
3. Fresh restart makes no difference.
4. Making a copy of the file (in case if some other process was blocking access to it etc.) and trying to read that copy fails in the same manner.
5. If I try to evaluate `crypto.ReadByte()` in the Watch window, I'm getting the following messages in that order:

   - `This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated`;
   - when I refresh it: `Function evaluation was aborted`
   - when I either refresh it or just wait a few seconds: `Unable to evaluate the expression. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.`

and the app is terminated, we're back to Visual Studio.

What is the problem here?

Comment: How is `Key` initialized? Looks like it might be incorrect in some way.

Comment: @Jeremy `Key` is hardcoded. It's a byte array of 8 first digits of Pi.

Comment: Does encoding / decoding using this key work properly? Try an ad-hoc unit test - at least that will eliminate that as a cause.

Comment: You need to run it with attached WinDBG

Comment: Im pretty sure that there is unmanaged code being called under the covers as the Cryptography layer is also available in Win32. The code is probably crashing in the unmanged portion and terminating the process.

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- Try using [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) with the **-t** option on your app. This should create a dump file when your app exits prematurely. Try the other options as well (e.g. **-e**) if that doesn't generate a useful dump.
- If that doesn't work, try running your app under WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's so late for answer, but maybe it help some one. i have the same problem and this answer help me [Debugger kills the application with no explanation (on a CryptoStream.ReadByte() call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673753/debugger-kills-the-application-with-no-explanation-on-a-cryptostream-readbyte)

if Your watch window contains an error message "Function evaluation was aborted." That probably means one of the properties displayed has an infinite recursion, like so:

```
readonly bool isSigned;
public bool IsSigned { get { return IsSigned; } }
```

Fix the infinite recursion and the problem should go away:

```
readonly bool isSigned;
public bool IsSigned { get { return isSigned; } }
```

You can catch the StackOverflowException when it is thrown using Visual Studio by selecting from the menu bar "Debug" -> "Exceptions" -> "Find..." -> type "stackoverflow" -> check "Thrown" for System.StackOverflowException -> "OK"